# how is Kinesis LATEST position recorded

Tags: streaming, amazon-kinesis

When Kinesis checkpoint is not used, there is a InitialPositionInStream.LATEST setting that supposedly let you restart kinesis receiving from the "latest tip". Could someone explain what exactly that is. If the receiver application was shut down and restarted, where would this latest tip information be stored for this purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't care where the previous worker stopped if you are using LATEST. When you are using this flag it means that you want to start processing records from NOW and you don't care about the history events.

If you want to continue the processing from a previous worker, you should use the sequence ID of the last checkpoint of that worker.

If you want to process all the history events that are available in the kinesis stream, you should use the TRIM_HORIZON flag.

See more details in the kinesis documentation for shard iterator type: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_GetShardIterator.html

Comment: Is there an option to track the position of the iterator on the stream and restart from there after a failure? I know the KCL does this, but can you also implement it yourself?